# How to integrate AMP in react Server Side Rendering(Razzle)?

Tags: react-redux, server-side-rendering, amp-html, razzle

I have been using [razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle) for Server side Rendering with react+redux. Now, i need to integrate AMP in this setup. I found few examples with [nextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/amp). Should i add amp.js in the main HTML or there should be separate server.js for rendering AMP pages and How. how to handle the `amp` routes with respect to existing routes.

Here is my server.js

```
  const markup = renderToString(
     sheets.collect(
       <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <App />
          </StaticRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
  ));


const css = sheets.toString();
      const finalState = store.getState();
      const html = `<!doctype html>
          <html lang="">
          <head>
              ${assets.client.css
                ? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${assets.client.css}">`
                : ''}
                ${css ? `<style id='jss-ssr'>${css}</style>` : ''}
                ${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
                  ? `<script src="${assets.client.js}" defer></script>`
                  : `<script src="${assets.client.js}" defer crossorigin></script>`}
          </head>
          <body>
              <div id="root">${markup}</div>
              <script>
                window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${serialize(finalState)}
              </script>
          </body>
      </html>`
```

Client.js

```
hydrate(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider> ,
  document.getElementById('root'),
    () => {
      const jssStyles = document.getElementById('jss-ssr');
      if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode)
        jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);  
    }
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('../common/containers/App', () => {
    hydrate(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  });
}

serviceWorker.register();
```

Comment: found a way to do this?

Comment: @karma not yet.